# Prisma schema not pulling the credentials from the db url environment variable in the .env file

Tags: next.js, prisma

In my schema.prisma I have the following:

```
datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("DB_URL")
}
```

In my .env file, which is in the root folder, I have the following:

```
DB_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@dbnamehere.cbshjkhplbrb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

I am getting an error during the build process. The error says
Authentication failed against database server at [db url], the provided database credentials for `postgres` are not valid.

When I replace, the url in the schema directly, as in the following:

```
datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = "postgresql://postgres:password@dbnamehere.cbshjkhplbrb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432"
}
```

The above works.

This tells me that the schema.prisma file is not pulling the DB_URL correctly.

Please tell me how to fix this?

I have tried running npx prisma generate and also npm run build, but neither of those work.

Thanks!